# Jupyter notebook sometimes not run with In [ ]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am coding Python in jupyter notebook and sometimes when I run a cell, it does not work and shows In [  ] and if I run it again, it works. It is really annoying because I have to check if one cell works or not before I run another cell. This problem began about a week ago. The content of the cell does not matter. [I run the cell and it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8VUg.png)

Comment: Please post as a text no image.

Comment: I can only post an image to show the problem because I am sure that it is not caused by the code. Even if I run an empty cell, this problem may happen.